# Which SVG elements are supported by Android studio and which are not?

Tags: android-studio, svg

I know android studio doesn't support all elements in SVG.

So far I know that:

```
<defs>
<stop>
<use> 
<linearGradient>
```

are not supported yet.

Here is reference to svg element
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element

Comment: yes can not to support full svg feature in android  i find the solution : try to convert your SVG exported to vector with this tool : https://shapeshifter.design/  if it's resolved your problem tell me to make it as a answer

Comment: @javaacm The tool you have specified is not showing the image layers. Instead it is showing a blank vector.

Answer (score 9):

The source code for the converter is here: [SVG2Vector.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/sdk-common/src/main/java/com/android/ide/common/vectordrawable/Svg2Vector.java)

From that you can see that, as of now, the following elements are supported (to some extent at least):

`<polygon>`, `<rect>`, `<circle>`, `<line>`, `<path>`, `<g>`