# When i use .svg file "ERROR @<image> is not supported" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, png

I want to create a Splash screen for my android application for this purpose i create ".svg" file by using three different ".png" images using Adobe XD. bust when i import ".svg" file through vector Asset it only show background of ".svg" image it does not show other images which i used to create this file for splash screen. I also used this http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ to get proper ".xml" file and past it in drawable folder but still no change. I am attaching images of my error [this is where error is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtJfH.png)

when i click on error foe more detail i [I found this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MEZ5.png)

I want to use my app logo for splash screen "Please Help" me an tell me how to use logo on splash screen i just started android development.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android Studio SVG importer only supports a subset of SVG.  Remember that it is converting the SVG to a VectorDrawable.  So only things that work in a VectorDrawable can be imported from the SVG.  Basically that means you must stick to just the vector shapes - rectangles, ellipses, paths etc

See: [Which SVG elements are supported by Android studio and which are not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390348/which-svg-elements-are-supported-by-android-studio-and-which-are-not)

If your SVG only contains PNG images, then there is no point in using an SVG anyway.  Just import your PNGs to your project and use an `ImageView` to display them.

If you really need to display an SVG.  Then use a library that properly supports SVGs.  Such as my one: [AndroidSVG](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg).

Comment: **AndroidSVG** is for Eclipse?

Comment: @IgorGanapolskyNo. It is a library for Android.